# SSIS Packages running on SQl Server Agent randomly cannot connect to Snowflake

Tags: ssis, odbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sql-server-agent

For the past week, multiple SSIS packages running on SQL Server Agent that load data into Snowflake have started returning the follow message randomly.

"Failed to acquire connection "snowflake". Connection may not be configured correctly or you may not have the right permissions on this connection."

We are seeing this message across multiple jobs and each of the jobs is loading multiple tables and its not happening on each call to Snowflake within the projects, but just on one or two tasks in jobs that have 100s.

We are using the 2.20.2 drivers from Snowflake

We have ran the jobs while WireShark was capturing network traffic and were received by the network team. They didn't have much luck because the ACK messages were not being shown.

We also ran Process Monitor while the jobs ran and we did not find anything that alluded to any issues

We also dug though the logs from the Snowflake driver and found the calls right before and right after, but no messages for the task that failed. Since those logs bounce around on which file they are sending to, its a bit hard to track sequential actions when multiple task on a job are running together.

We also installed SnowCD and ran it and it returned a full success message.

The user that runs the jobs on SQL Server Agent is an Admin on the server and has SysAdmin rights on the Sql Sever instance.

The warehouse the drivers are connected to are a size Large with a max of 3 clusters (was at 1 when the issue started, but upped it to 3 to see if that helped)

Jobs are running on Windows Server 2016 DataCenter in Azure
SQL Server instance is Sql Sever 2016 13.0.4604.0

We cannot figure out why we are suddenly and randomly using connection to Snowflake.

Comment: How are you loading the data into Snowflake through SSIS? In general SSIS should not insert rows directly into Snowflake. It should write files such as CSV that get loaded into Snowflake.

Comment: The commands that are failing are non data load tasks (though we use CSV files loaded via copy into but those have not failed). We have commands that truncate the initial tables first that are failing and some insert into commands failing down stream in the package. All of those are since Execute Sql tasks in SSIS.

Comment: That should all be okay. Sounds like something technical support should look into. If it's a random stability issue with the driver or connection, you could test with the CData ODBC driver for Snowflake. It is not free but has a free thirty day trial.

Comment: Maybe turn on ODBC trace and check the logs.  Also try disabling OCSP check.

Comment: Does SSIS have a setting to keep the connection alive? Maybe something similar to Snowflake's parameter? https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/parameters.html#client-session-keep-alive

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas to help get these packages working:

Add a retry to the tasks that are failing.  The task would move onto the next step only upon success: 
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5625/how-to-retry-sql-server-integration-services-ssis-control-flow-tasks/

You can also combine the truncate and insert into one step using the `insert overwrite into` command which will allow your package to run quicker and have one less task for failure:
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/insert.html#insert-using-overwrite

Once the SSIS packages are consistently completing, you can analyze the logs at the point of failure to see if there is any pattern to help you identify the root cause.

Comment: We do have retrys set up on the packages themselves to retry twice before failing. I have not seen an easy way to retry an individual task within a package without a lengthy loop process.

Comment: As for the "insert overwrite into", I had seen that before but it didnt stick in my mind. That would eliminate half the calls to the DB and will try that in our jobs going forward. We havent see the error in the past few days.